# Compile files only if needing

Tags: c++, build, makefile

I have couple of cpp and hpp files in directory `./src`. I compile all cpp files in one binary file, say `./bin/run`. I want to re-compile only if I need i.e it or one of its header was changed.

I, probably, can create Makefile where file will be recompiled if and only if it was changed, but it's quite uncomfortable because big part of my code is in the headers. (It's not going to be changed, because the product is header itself and cpp files are tests).

I want to store temporary `.o` files in `./build`

I know about `g++ -MM` function but I'm not sure how to use it.

I'll glad to see solutions that use not necessary `make` but any other system possible if they are easy enough.

**UPD**
I'll try to clarify, what's the problem is:

New cpp's maybe created, includes may be added or gone, etc. I don't want to edit my makefile each time.

Comment: Why don't you want to use make?  That's intended to solve exactly this problem.

Comment: Why can't you still use make, but in the case of headers, set the headers to be make targets rather than the cpp files?

Comment: You could use [SCons](http://scons.org) which automatically determines dependencies in C++ code.

Comment: @Adam: Oh. I mean, not __only__ make, I edited it.

Comment: @slugonamission, because I don't compile headers, I compile cpp's that depends on headers, then edit headers and compile cpp's again

Comment: Then create rules for myfile.o, which is generated from myfile.cpp, which contains myfile.h as a dependency.

Comment: Actually, see my (upcoming answer for a sample)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention `g++ -MM`, which can do what you're trying to do:

```
include $(ALLOBJ:%.o=%.d)

%.d: %.cxx
    @echo making dependencies for $<
    @g++ -MM -MP $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
    @sed -i 's,$*\.o,& $@ ,g' $@
```

Basically this defines a rule that creates `.d` files from `.cxx` files. The `.d` files are, in turn, required by the `include` statement, which requires one for each `.o` file in `ALLOBJ`.

The last line in the dependency rule is the 'sed magic' that makes the dependency files regenerate themselves. If you think regular expressions are hacks at best, and evil more often than not, you can [use the `-MT` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12876363/915501).

Comment: This is a pretty good solution, but will break if a header file is removed: if `foo.cpp` includes `bar.h`, then the user modifies `foo.cpp` to do without it and removes `bar.h`, then Make sees that `foo.d` must be updated, but can't do it because `foo.dep` depends on `bar.h` which cannot be found.

Comment: good point, I usually define a special command to remove dependencies in this case, but you can also just use `-include`, right?

Comment: but yeah, I guess it's easier to just use `-include`... maybe harder to debug if something else is going wrong (since it will cause make to ignore errors in the `include` call).

Comment: Uuh, seemd to be almost done. Now I have problem with this `sed` line. I'm not know about `sed`. Now it's generate file `build/%name.d` as expected with code `main.o build/main.d : tests/main.cpp` which isn't expected. First of all I don't understand why we need `build/main.d` here, and the second: we have to add `build/` before `main.o`. Could you please provide code for this(I quess it's 1 sed line). Thanks

Comment: the `.d` file depends on the headers too: if those change it should be rebuilt. As for the second question, just replace 's,$*\.o,& $@ ,g' with 's,$*\.o,build/& $@ ,g'

Comment: @Shep, Oh, sure, didn't notice that. Thank a lot

Comment: If you `-include`, you get `foo.d` because `foo.d` exists; Make then sees that `foo.d` must be rebuilt, can't find `bar.h`, and aborts.

Comment: Hmm, how do I show how to compile `.o` files? May I just append [tab]+Compilation line? And another question is that I'll have 2 rules for every `.d` file. Is it OK? How it'll be processed?

Answer (score 2):

To solve the problem I mentioned (`-include` is not a good solution), I use something like this:

```
build/%.o: %.cpp
    @$(CC) -MD -c -Wall -o $@ $<
    @cp build/$*.d build/$*.P
    @sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^[^:]*: *//' -e 's/ *\\$$//' \
         -e '/^$$/ d' -e 's/$$/ :/' < build/$*.P >> build/$*.d
    @rm build/$*.P

-include build/*.d
```

No `%.d rule is needed.

**EDIT:**

@JackKelly has [**cough*, *choke**] shown me a better way to get effectively the same dependency file:

```
build/%.o: %.cpp
    @$(CC) -MD -c -Wall -o $@ $<
    @$(CC) -MM -MP -Wall -o $*.d $<

-include build/*.d
```

Ye, you can have multiple rules for the same target, as long as only one of them has commands; the prerequisites accumulate. The idea is to get a file like this:

```
file.o: file.cpp headerfile.h
headerfile.h:
```

The second line (`headerfile.h:`) is a rule for `headerfile.h` that has no prerequisites or commands. It does nothing, but it's a rule, so if `headerfile.h` is missing, Make is satisfied.

Comment: Can you clarify bit more, what will happen?  As I see, I'll have 2 rules for every `.o` file. Is it OK? How it'll be processed?

Comment: I got quite strange .d file (after change -MD to -MMD to avoid std headers, same with -MD):  http://pastebin.com/5ct1da35 am I right that `file.o: file.cpp[\n]
file.cpp: headers` expected?

Comment: apparently you can get around this funny sed script with the -MP option, comment?

Comment: sorry, not the point, I've been looking for that flag for months without knowing it and was happy to find it

Answer (score 1):

The outline of a solution is as follows:

- Use auxiliary dependency files for each source file (that is, create `foo.dep` for `foo.c`, `bar.dep` for `bar.c` etc)
- Use `gcc -MM` to create the dependency files
- In order to force `make` to do this automatically, use `foo.c` as a prerequisite for `foo.dep` and `foo.o`; this requires some minor `sed` magic on the output of `gcc -MM`
- Include all the dependency files in your main makefile; this is a key step that makes this approach possible.

The last step is written as follows:

```
-include $(dependency_files)
```

This is very tricky but possible; see the [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html#Include) for more information.

Comment: Oh, I now see main idea, and I'll try it, thank you, but is it easy way to make `$(dependency_files)` if I don't want to write it explicitly if I have `$(cpp_files) = tests/*.cpp`? (Seems it's not `tests/*.dep` because some of them may be not generate on first build)

Comment: See @Shep's answer (the part with the `%.o=%.d`)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Make, you just need to specify the headers in your rule's sensitivity list. For example

```
myfile.o: myfile.cpp
    gcc -c myfile.o myfile.cpp ${LDFLAGS}    # This is optional. make can infer this line.
```

Turns into

```
myfile.o: myfile.cpp myfile.h
    gcc -c myfile.o myfile.cpp ${LDFLAGS}    # Again, optional.
```

Now, whenever `myfile.h` changes, `myfile.cpp` will be rebuild. More headers can be chained in a similar way.

Comment: Oh, you're right, that's possible. But actually I want to do something to make `make` or any other tool work for me

Comment: Huh? Why do you want to maximise the amount of work you're doing?

Comment: Hah, not maximal work of `make`, of course. on the contrary, I suppose rewrite dep-lists after each includes edit is hard and I try to avoid it