# To include or -include auto-generated dependencies?

Tags: makefile, g++

I like to use the `g++ -MM` feature to auto-build my dependencies. The way I do this is as follows:

```
include $(ALLOBJ:%.o=%.d)

%.d: %.cxx
    @echo making dependencies for $<
    @g++ -MM $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
    @sed -i 's,$*\.o,& $@ ,g' $@
```

Basically I can give this rule `ALLOBJ`, and it will:

1. convert every `.o` name to a `.d` name, and `include` it,
2. when it can't find a `.d`, it will create it from the `.cxx` file

   - the final line of the `%.d: %.cxx` rule will add the name of the `.d` file to the file itself, so that the dependency will be updated automatically.

The issue arises when I remove a header: the `.d` file still expects to find it, and make will get upset when it's not there. One solution is to replace `include` with `-include`, and to build the dependencies within the compile rule. Unfortunately this requires a dependency generation line for each compile rule, and will also ignore all other `include` errors (which seems risky). Is there some other simple way to auto-build dependencies which avoids this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the [g++](/questions/tagged/g%2b%2b) manual a bit more, and thanks to @jackKelly and @Beta's responses above, I found the following solution:

```
include $(ALLOBJ:%.o=%.d)

%.d: %.cxx
    @echo making dependencies for $<
    @g++ -MM -MP -MT $*.d -MT $*.o $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

To summarize the flags:

- `-MM`: build dependencies (rather than compiling)
- `-MP`: build 'dummy' targets for all headers. This prevents make from complaining when headers are deleted and thus can't be found.
- `-MT`: specify the targets for the rule. This allows us to tell make the `.d` file depends on the headers without resorting to the ugly sed rule.

I don't believe my solution is any more correct than @Beta's solution. I tend to use multiple compile rules for C++ files in the same makefile, so having a single dependency rule for all of them is slightly cleaner (in my case) than generating the dependencies in each compile rule.

Answer (score 2):

To restate my answer to [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866155/compile-files-only-if-needing/12868198#12868198), I do it this way:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    @echo making $@ and dependencies for $< at the same time
    @$(CC) -MD -c $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<
    @cp $*.d $*.P
    @sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^[^:]*: *//' -e 's/ *\\$$//' \
         -e '/^$$/ d' -e 's/$$/ :/' < $*.P >> $*.d
    @rm $*.P

-include $(ALLOBJ:%.o=%.d)
```

**EDIT:**

It... It produces the dependency file, but more cleanly and without the `sed` command:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    @echo making $@ and dependencies for $< at the same time
    @$(CC) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<
    @$(CC) -MM -MP $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $*.d

-include *.d
```

So now I have to modify the `%.o` rule in my own makefiles. From now on there'll be a little bit of @JackKelly in *everything I compile*, mocking me. Oh, this is a black day.

Comment: two questions: What does `-MD` do? What's going on with eh really long sed line?

Comment: @Shep: `-MD` creates *two* files, `foo.o` and `foo.d`. But this `foo.d` lists `foo.h` as a preq of `foo.o`, so it's subject to the problem you describe. The long `sed` command modifies `foo.d`, appending the preqs as targets of rules without commands (e.g. `foo.h:`). This is enough to soothe Make and prevent the error; `foo.h` is missing, but there's a rule for it, so Make trusts that everything is taken care of.

Comment: @Beta: Why don't you just pass `-MP` to `gcc`?

Comment: @JackKelly: Well, because, you see, uh... that's because... *because I didn't know about `-MP`! Damn you, Jack Kelly! Damn you to Hell!*